# export results on python: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, anaconda

I have trouble writing to a csv file in Python. I wrote this code which reads from a csv and extracts sequences to a list:

```
from pandas import read_csv
# load data
filename = 'C:/Users/asus/Desktop/travail/descretized-dataset.csv'
names = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K']
data=read_csv(filename, names=names, delimiter=';')
array = data.values

s=[]
L=[]

for i in range(len(array)):
    s.append(array[i])
    if (array[i,0]==1):
        L.append(s)
        s=[]

L
```

This code work correctly. Now, I want to save the result to a file on my PC. So, I added this part:

```
raw_data = {L}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['array'])
df.to_csv('C:/Users/asus/Desktop/travail/data.csv')
df
```

But I'm getting this error:

> {TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'}

Can you help me to correctly export my result to a csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is because of the below snippet.

```
raw_data = {L}
```

Change it to

```
raw_data = L #or df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns = ['array'])
```

Comment: You are Welcome :)